# How can I get my datagridview value to populate my boomarked form field in word

Tags: c#, datagridview, ms-word

I am new to C# and having trouble inserting some text from a datagridview into a word document which has a table fileld with bookmarks.

I have tried different methods of casting the datagridview value as text and also tried casting to a string rather than a range but it does not seem to accept this method.  It seems to work for a combobox value but not a datagridview value.

```
    private void BtnMtdmin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordMinutes = null;
        wordMinutes = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        wordMinutes.Visible = true;

        Document docMinutes =  wordMinutes.Documents.Open(@"\\myfilelocation\MeetingMinutesTemplate.docx");

        Bookmark MeetingName = docMinutes.Bookmarks["MeetingName"];
        Range MeetingNameRange = MeetingName.Range;
        MeetingNameRange.Text = txtMtdnme.Text;

        Bookmark MeetingDate = docMinutes.Bookmarks["MeetingDate"];
        Range MeetingDateRange = MeetingDate.Range;
        MeetingDateRange.Text = dtpMtddte.Value.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy ") + dtpMtdtme.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt");

        Bookmark Section = docMinutes.Bookmarks["Section"];
        Range SectionRange = Section.Range;
        SectionRange.Text = cbxMtddep.SelectedItem.ToString();

        Bookmark Supervisor = docMinutes.Bookmarks["Supervisor"];
        Range SupervisorRange = Supervisor.Range;
        SupervisorRange.Text = cbxMtdsup.SelectedItem.ToString();

        Bookmark MeetingReason = docMinutes.Bookmarks["MeetingReason"];
        Range MeetingReasonRange = MeetingReason.Range;
        MeetingReasonRange.Text = txtMtdrsn.Text;

        Bookmark Name1 = docMinutes.Bookmarks["Name1"];
        Range Name1Range = Name1.Range;
        Name1Range = dgvMtdatt.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

I expect the value from the datagridview to be displayed in my word document that is created when I press the button.

All fields work except the Name1 value which complains that I am trying to implicitly convert a string to a range.

Comment: If you could please also explain why it works for a combobox but not a datagridview I would really appreciate it.

Comment: `Name1Range.Text = ...`? Looks like you forgot to use the `.Text` property only with that range object (which happens to be used with the DataGridView), thus, the problem appears to have nothing to do with DGV.

Comment: ok Im not sure how I missed that, thanks!